# Execute trigger after table update

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, triggers

I'm trying to refresh a view when a master table is updated.

The view uses the fields from the master table as pivot.

So the CREATE VIEW procedure needs the committed values in the master table:

```
mastertable:
id      tipusVal
----------------
 1      val1
 2      val2
 3      val3

variacionsTemps table:
id  tipusVal  valor  mes
------------------------
1    val1     10     3
2    val1     10     4
3    val3     2      4
4    val1     10     5
5    val2     9      5
6    val1     6      5

resum view:
mes  sum_val1   sum_val2   sum_val3
-----------------------------------
3    10         0          0
4    10         0          2
5    16         9          0
```

So when master table is updated then the view should be re-created.
Right now I've managed to execute the "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW" procedure with a `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` but what I found is that the procedure is getting the old values from mastertable.

Trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RCREATE_RESUM
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF tipusVal ON mastertable
DECLARE
  PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
  CREATE_RESUM_VIEW();
END;
```

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CREATE_RESUM_VIEW AS
  mAggCols VARCHAR2(2048);
  mStmt VARCHAR2(2048);
BEGIN

  SELECT LISTAGG('SUM(CASE WHEN tipusVal=''' || tipusVal || ''' THEN valor ELSE 0 END) AS sum_' || tipusVal , ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id)
  INTO mAggrCols
  FROM mastertable;

  mStmt := 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW RESUM AS SELECT mes, ' || mAggrCols || ' FROM variacionsTemps GROUP BY mes';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE mStmt;
END CREATE_RESUM_VIEW;
```

I've been reading [in the oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/sqloperations.htm#BABDHGAB) and I understand that the main transaction is stopped until the trigger finishes, so this is the reason why the values are not updated. So I've tried to remove the `PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` but then the trigger fails as 'cannot commit in trigger'...

Is there a way to execute a trigger after the transaction has been committed?
Or is there any way/other way/better way to achieve it?

Comment: you could look up dynamic PIVOT techniques, and not try to rebuild this view

Comment: Dynamic PIVOT are for known columns (I know I could use PIVOT XML but I would need the columns for unparsing the xml result and moreover it can be really slow view). The main problem here is that I don't know the columns to pivot when I create the view.

Comment: I think Ask Tom has some solutions for unknown column in the pivot.

Comment: Please, could you point the article? I've been looking for this solution but didn't found any and I would like to know for a pivot (not xml) solution for unknown column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact I found the solution with a `DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER RCREATE_RESUM
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE OF tipusVal ON mastertable
DECLARE
  jobNum NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT(
    jobNum,
    'BEGIN CREATE_RESUM_VIEW(); END;',
    SYSDATE);
END;
```